# React-Native Hide Android Bottom Buttons (Fullscreen)

Tags: fullscreen, react-native

I want to hide bottom buttons in android (react-native)

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add or update the code into AndroidManifest.xml

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize`

Comment: I want to do just in click button